# OutOfMemoryException receiving data from WebServices

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, out-of-memory

I have an application that communicates with Java webservices using WCF clients. One of the services returns a moderately big result (about 100 Mb) and sometimes we get an OutOfMemoryException:

> System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32)
>   System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32)
>   System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
>   System.Xml.XmlMtomReader+MimePart.GetBuffer(Int32, Int32 ByRef)
>   System.Xml.XmlMtomReader.Initialize(System.IO.Stream, System.String,
>   System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas, Int32)
>   System.Xml.XmlMtomReader.SetInput(System.IO.Stream,
>   System.Text.Encoding[], System.String,
>   System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas, Int32,
>   System.Xml.OnXmlDictionaryReaderClose)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MtomMessageEncoder.TakeStreamedReader(System.IO.Stream,
>   System.String)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MtomMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(System.IO.Stream,
>   Int32, System.String)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadStreamedMessage(System.IO.Stream)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(System.Exception
>   ByRef)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory+HttpRequestChannel+HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(System.TimeSpan)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message,
>   System.TimeSpan)
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message,
>   System.TimeSpan)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(System.String,
>   Boolean, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime,
>   System.Object[], System.Object[], System.TimeSpan)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMethodCallMessage,
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.MessageData
>   ByRef, Int32)

Our WCF Client ....

The amount of data is not big enough to create a real OutOfMemoryException as the application is a 32 bit app consuming about 400 - 600 MB and the response is aroung 100Mb so something else must be happening.

Any idea?

Comment: If you do that (receiving 100mb chunk) often AND your app is 32-bit (why, by the way?) - your memory might get fragmented, so there is no _continuous_ 100MB chunk of available memory.

Comment: Here is a good article on this by the way: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory/

Comment: Fragmentation is irrelevant here. All current operating systems used paged virtual memory. Fragmentation happens with contiguous allocation.

Comment: Any program that works heavily in the LOH will get OOME. 100mb >>>85kB. So yes. You will get OOMEs. You can try using streaming mode instead of buffered mode. That way the Serializer will write directly to the NetworkStream rather than a MemoryStream/Buffer.

Comment: It is 32 bit as it depends on devices that only have 32 bit drivers :\ So ... fragmentation counts or not? To me the set_Capacity smells strange. Maybe it is allocating more than needed?

Comment: Check you are disposing objects correctly (use the memory profiler to make sure you have no references handing around). It's not the size of the response that matters (bar the limit on a string), but how big your set of objects are after the response is serialized to objects. It may help to post your code.

Comment: Well you can read that article above (it's by Eric Lippert by the way) and decide for yourself if fragmentation is relevant or not, instead of trust some random commentators.

Comment: @A.Wabbi  This occurs because we are allocating large blocks of memory (approximately 256MB due to List<byte> being extended multiple times upto 100MB). Then these `byte[]` live on the Large Object Heap, which isn't compacted. Ever. So we use up progressively higher virtual memory addresses, until we run out of memory addresses (as long as the collection and allocation is not done in the same order).

Comment: @A.Wabbi Evk is definitely right here. I have had the same issue before, and I personally solved it by overriding the Serialization process with a `FileStream` rather than a `MemoryStream` as the buffer.

Comment: @Aron Running out of memory addresses may be the reason, but I insist on forgetting about "memory fragmentation". It cannot be "so there is no continuous 100MB chunk of available memory". In fact, the article proves exactly what I say.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things that lead to such behavior:

1. 32bit process can only address 2GB (sometimes 3GB) of it's *virtual* address space (1-2GB is reserved, and with 32-bit pointer you can only address 4GB).
2. .NET stores large objects (which are bigger than 85000 bytes) on a special Large Object Heap. This heap is by default not *compacted* (and in .NET versions before 4.5.1 - never compacted at all). Suppose you allocated 40MB, then 10MB then 70MB of memory. After a while, 40MB and 70MB were garbage collected. Now you want to allocate 100MB chunk. If Large Object Heap were compacted - you could have at least 110MB of continuous free address space. But it's not and so you have two gaps of 40MB and 70MB and you cannot allocate your 100MB chunk because of this.

So even if there is plenty free physical RAM on that machine (and even if not - there is always swap), you may not be able to get a pointer to continuous chunk of address space large enough. In this case `OutOfMemoryException` would be thrown.

Couple of ways to solve this:

1. Use 64-bit process.
2. Reuse (pool) memory chunks by reusing byte arrays. For example WCF provides (and uses) such [BufferManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.buffermanager.aspx).
3. .NET 4.5.1 provides a way to compact Large Object Heap, but it does not really solves your problem I think, just kind of delays it. You can compact LOH once (you cannot force it to compact on every collection) by doing:

   ```
   GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
   GC.Collect();
   ```

Comment: What about moving the WCF client from buffered to streamed? Regarding 1) it's not the problem here as the process is consuming only 600Mb.

Comment: Yes moving to streamed should help that too. As for 32-bit process - it's certainly a problem, because the issue here is it cannot allocate large enough chunk of _address space_. In 32bit process address space is just 2 GB as I desribed. In 64bit process it's several terabytes. It's _not_ related in any way how much physical memory there is, or how much memory your application consumes at the moment (those 600MB you mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a the [WCF WebServiceHost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/justinjsmith/2007/07/02/webservicehost-vs-servicehost/) and setting the configuration to not limit buffer or Message size:

```
    using System;
    using System.ServiceModel.Web;

    private WebServiceHost webHost;

    public void Start()
    {
        webHost.Opening += ConfigureEnpointBinding;

        webHost.Open();
    }

    private void ConfigureEnpointBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var endpointBinding = (System.ServiceModel.WebHttpBinding)
            ((WebServiceHost)sender)
            .Description
            .Endpoints
            .Single(endpoint => endpoint.Contract.ContractType == typeof(IYourInterface))
            .Binding;

        endpointBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
        endpointBinding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
    }
```